# Bayesian spatial model, sampling error

Tags: statistics, bayesian

I have a problem with my code, multivariate poison with spatial correlation, which is written with Openbugs.

The code can not update samples.
Do you have any idea about the problem?

Following you can see the first part of the code. 
you can find the complete code [here. (click)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzwgJ-5xoHbqVm9RX2FZOXBvN0U/view?usp=sharing)

model {

# likelihood
  for (i in 1:407) {
  HO[i] ~ dpois(lambdaHO[i])
    lambdaHO[i] <- exp(rhoHO[i] + betaHO*ln[i])
  }

betaHO ~ dnorm (0,0.001)

# CAR prior distribution for spatial:
  rhoHO[1:407] ~ car.normal(adj[], weights[], num[], tauSp)

for(k in 1:802) {
weights[k] <- 1
}

# other priors

tauSp <- pow(sdSp, -2)
  sdSp ~ dunif(0, 5)
}

## inits 1

list(betaHO=0,tau=1, sdSp=2 )

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question might be better asked on StackOverflow, or maybe CrossValidated.

Comment: thank you. 
I will add the question there too.

Comment: There is a MathJax guide to help with typesetting equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Also, please don't ask users to follow a link to be able to answer a question, especially a link with no preview. Type in the salient points.

Comment: here the typing is as it is in the real code with no difference. because it is written in winbugs, it is written simple